# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] in Drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

A former custom Drupal 6 module switches between POST and GET request.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'POST':
       ...
       break;
    case 'GET':
       ...
       break;
}
```

I just started to adopt this module to Drupal 7. But the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is always GET. Even when the request is POST e.g.
    curl -i -X POST http://myurl.com/mypath

I found some issues but no solution:

Expose $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] logic outside of RESTServer->handle()
https://drupal.org/node/1691638

It must be posible to get some REST functionality with Services and the integrated RESTServer, but it so much overhead.

Does somebody have good and easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect method using $_GET & $_POST variables or other query data.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  // POST
}
else {
  // GET
}
```

This works, except case of empty POST query, without any data/file. You can use this as temporary solution.

Comment: Even $_GET and $_POST is everytime $_GET also when the request is a POST-Request :( It's the same like $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']. Drupal 7 converts every POST-Request to GET